# reading multiple sheet in an excel file using openxml sdk 2.0

Tags: c#, vb.net, openxml-sdk

I did to extract data from single sheet in excel, but need to store data from excel where there are sheet more than1. but not getting any how to do it.
below is the code

```
Protected Sub upl_excel(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnfromexcel.Click
        'Save the uploaded Excel file.
        Dim filePath As String = Server.MapPath("./UplExcel_Files") + Path.GetFileName(c_upload.PostedFile.FileName)
        c_upload.SaveAs(filePath)

        'Open the Excel file in Read Mode using OpenXml.
        Using doc As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, False)
            'Read the first Sheet from Excel file.
            Dim sheet As Sheet = doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.GetFirstChild(Of Sheet)()
            'Get the Worksheet instance.
            Dim worksheet As Worksheet = TryCast(doc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id.Value), WorksheetPart).Worksheet
            'Fetch all the rows present in the Worksheet.
            Dim rows As IEnumerable(Of Row) = worksheet.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)().Descendants(Of Row)()
            'Create a new DataTable.
            Dim dt1 As New DataTable()
            'Loop through the Worksheet rows.
            For Each row As Row In rows
                'Use the first row to add columns to DataTable.
                If row.RowIndex.Value = 1 Then
                    For Each cell As Cell In row.Descendants(Of Cell)()
                        dt1.Columns.Add(GetValue(doc, cell))
                    Next
                Else
                    'Add rows to DataTable.
                    dt1.Rows.Add()
                    Dim i As Integer = 0
                    For Each cell As Cell In row.Descendants(Of Cell)()
                        dt1.Rows(dt1.Rows.Count - 1)(i) = GetValue(doc, cell)
                        i += 1
                    Next
                End If
            Next
            grdChemistry1.DataSource = dt1
            grdChemistry1.DataBind()
            ''2nd child
            'GridView1.DataSource = dt
            'GridView1.DataBind()
        End Using
    End Sub

Private Function GetValue(doc As SpreadsheetDocument, cell As Cell) As String
        Dim value As String = cell.CellValue.InnerText
        If cell.DataType IsNot Nothing AndAlso cell.DataType.Value = CellValues.SharedString Then
            Return doc.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.ChildElements.GetItem(Integer.Parse(value)).InnerText
        End If
        Return value
    End Function
```

Any idea would be appreciated how to achieve it.

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate the WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets collection?

Comment: @Hursey how to iterate through multiple sheets in exce and store it in a gridview

Comment: With a for each loop.  For each sheet in doc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets ... Next

Comment: @Hursey i got for each loop but how given code is for 'Read the first Sheet from Excel file. and insert into gridview, for getting second and third sheet what will be the code i am not aware .